# ¿Cómo leer la información de una base de datos cleardb creada en heroku?

Tags: mysql, heroku, users-roles

Con los credenciales dado por ClearDB en Heroku fue capaz de crear una database:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://user:password@host.cleardb.com/heroku_02c821a76ca04c8')
df.to_sql('attributs', engine,if_exists='append')
```

Pero al leerlas informaciones parece que faltan derechos. Intenté:

```
ubu@DESKTOP-QL4RO3V:/mnt/c/Windows/system32$ mysql -u user -p'password' -h host.cleardb.com -D heroku_02c821a76ca04c8
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 47008095
Server version: 5.6.50-log MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2021, Oracle and/or its affiliates.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+----------------------------------+
| Tables_in_heroku_02c821a76ca04c8 |
+----------------------------------+
| attributs                        |
+----------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)

mysql> use attributs;
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'attributs'
```

Entonces como leer las informaciones en la mia database? Necisto ser root ? O hacer un nuevo usario ?

Comment: Necesitas [garantizar](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/grant.html) acceso a tu usuario. Por ejemplo, las siguientes 2 instrucciones lo hacen posible. Primero ejecutas esto: `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'user'@'%';`. Eso da permiso al usuario `user` a todo el sistema, desde cualquier conexión (`%`). Luego, para aplicar los cambios ejecutas la siguiente sentencia: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`. Con eso le has garantizado acceso correctamente a tu usuario. Saludos

Comment: Recuerda que para hacer esto has de ingresar como usuario con privilegios, es decir, como `root`. Saludos